# How to calculate this difference in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file named Test1.dat and its content's are as follows

```
Abcxxxxxxxxxxx_123.dat@10:10:15
Bcdxxxxxxxxxxx_145.dat@10:15:23
Cssxxxxxxxxxxx_567.dat@10:26:56
Fgsxxxxxxxxxxx_823.dat@10:46:56
Kssxxxxxxxxxxx_999.dat@11:15:23
```

Please note that after the @ symbol it is the HH:MM:SS format that follows. My question now is I want to calculate the time difference between the current time and the time present in the files and fetch only those filenames where time difference is more than 30 Mins. So if current time is 11:00:00, I want to fetch files that have arrived 30 minutes before so basically the first three files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -F@ '$2>=from && $2<=to' from="$(date +%H:%M:%S -d -30min)" to="$(date +%H:%M:%S)" file
```

If you only need to get the last 30 min (In you case you need the first one since you do not like 11:30):

```
awk -F@ '$2>=from' from="$(date +%H:%M:%S -d -30min)" file
```

Comment: hi, how do I print the lines.?

Comment: @user2647888 Since this `awk` only has to test part, and no action part, it will do the default action: `{print $0}` (print the line). So this `awk` should do it all.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use bash script and get the result

```
#!/bin/bash
current=`date  '+%s'`
needed_time=`echo "$current - 60 * 30" | bc`
while read line ; do 
    time=`echo $line |sed -r 's/[^@]*.(.*)/\1/g'` 
    user_time=`date -d $time '+%s'`
            if [ $user_time -le $needed_time ] ; then
            echo "$line"
    fi
done < file_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be this the answer?

```
awk -F@ '{ts = systime(); thirty_mins = 30 * 60; thirty_mins_ago = ts - thirty_mins;  if ($2 < strftime("%H:%M:%S", thirty_mins_ago)) print $2 }' <file.txt
```

`strftime` is a GAWK (gnu awk) extention.

Comment: `strftime` is a `gnu awk` extention, so you should add this information.

Comment: Sure, now i see to update my post with you information.